# How to correctly implement InputStream.mark() when mark is not supported

Tags: java, inputstream

This is a question about correctly implementing Java's `InputStream` interface.

I have an implementation that **does not support** mark/reset functionality. Therefore it returns false from the `markSupported` method. How should I implement the `mark` method in this case? That is, if somebody calls `mark` despite having been told that mark is not supported, how should this be handled?

The two obvious choices are to (a) ignore it and do nothing; or (b) throw `UnsupportedOperationException`. The API JavaDocs do not offer any guidance on which is preferred.

Comment: This appears to be described in the reset docs [InputStream#reset](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#reset()) . Throw an exception when they try to reset.

Comment: Yes, `InputStream#reset` does throw an `IOException` but this cannot be thrown from `mark` because it does not declare `throws IOException`. So we can only throw unchecked exceptions from `mark`.

Comment: Don't throw an exception from mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like typical implementations within the JDK do nothing, and throw an IOException if `reset` is invoked:

java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream:

```
public synchronized void mark(int readlimit) {
}

public synchronized void reset() throws IOException {
    throw new IOException("mark/reset not supported");
}
```

java.io.PushbackInputStream:

```
public synchronized void mark(int readlimit) {
}

public synchronized void reset() throws IOException {
    throw new IOException("mark/reset not supported");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing like the class `InputStream`does, i.e.

- `mark()` : do nothing as stated in the javadoc "The mark method of InputStream does nothing."
- `reset()` : throw an I/O exception as stated in the javadoc "The method reset for class InputStream does nothing except throw an IOException."

Javadoc link : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html